# Sequence of arrival of messages in the actor mail box when using ask and tell

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have confusion on what is the sequence of messages arrived in the mailbox in the following code:

```
class myAct extends Actor {
def receive = {
  case 1 =>
    println(1)
  case 2 =>
    sender ! 90
  case 3 =>
    println(3)
}
```

}

In the driver I am sending messages to the actor

```
myActor ! 1
myActor.ask(2).mapTo[Int].onComplete {
case Success(x) =>
  println(x)
case Failure(ex) =>
  println(ex)}
myActor ! 3
```

The question is in what order will the messages be delivered to the mail box. Will 1 always arrive first. will 3 always arrive last. Is there a possibility of 2 arriving before 1.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific section of the documentation on [Message Ordering](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#message-ordering).  If your "driver" is another Actor then the ordering is clear.  From the documentation:

> The rule more specifically is that for a given pair of actors,
>   messages sent directly from the first to the second will not be
>   received out-of-order. The word directly emphasizes that this
>   guarantee only applies when sending with the tell operator to the
>   final destination, not when employing mediators or other message
>   dissemination features (unless stated otherwise).

If the driver is not inside of an Actor then the [default implicit sender](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/index.html#akka.actor.ActorRef@!(message:Any)(implicitsender:akka.actor.ActorRef):Unit) is `Actor.noSender`.  Per Konrad's comment it seems that the ordering is still preserved in this case as well.

Comment: The order is still guaranteed when `!` then `?` is done from a non-Actor. It's as simple as "! will happen before ?". FYI `?` is just a special `!` anyway - that does things when it receives a relpy in a special actor that is created when you do ?.

Comment: @Konrad'ktoso'Malawski Answer updated accordingly, thank you for the clarification.